# Whenever I try deserialize my json with enum, I keep on getting errors

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, enumeration, json-deserialization

This is my enum code

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        public enum SystemSwitch
        {
            EmergencyHeat = 0,
            Heat = 1,
            Off = 2,
            Cool = 3,
            Autoheat = 4,
            Autocool = 5,
            SouthernAway = 6,
            Unknown = 7
        }
```

And I am to deserialize this json

```
var a = @"{'SystemSwitch': 'Heat','HeatCoolMode': 'Cool'}";
            try
            {
                var parsedEventData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemSwitch>(a);
                Console.WriteLine(parsedEventData);
            }
```

But I received an exception saying

```
{"Unexpected token StartObject when parsing enum. Path '', line 1, position 1."}
```

And If I try with the json string

```
string a = "'SystemSwitch':'Cool'";
```

I get

```
{"Error converting value \"SystemSwitch\" to type 'Testing.Program+SystemSwitch'. Path '', line 1, position 14."}
```

Comment: @Jawad Not true at all, single quotes are fine for JSON.Net. The problem is that OP is trying to deserialise directly to an enum and not a class that contains the enum values.

Comment: Technically single quotes are not allowed, according to the spec. JSON.NET does allow them though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deserialise directly to an enum like that, you need a container of some sort. For example:

```
public class Container
{
    public SystemSwitch SystemSwitch { get; set; }
    public SystemSwitch HeatCoolMode { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var a = @"{'SystemSwitch': 'Heat','HeatCoolMode': 'Cool'}";
var parsedEventData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(a);
Console.WriteLine(parsedEventData.SystemSwitch);
Console.WriteLine(parsedEventData.HeatCoolMode);
```

Which will output:

> Heat
>
> Cool